# Hook function to shared library unloading

Tags: linux, elf, dynamic-linking

I want to add hook function, which will be called when shared library is unloaded. Library is linked on complitaion. Is it possible to do such thing? Maybe gcc has flag for it?

I saw similar solution for loading library on runtime, but it doesn't meet my expectations.

Comment: AFAIK the a library that is linked to at compile time stays loaded until the program ends.

Comment: But isn't there a small unit of time before program ends when this library is unloaded?
What I would like to achieve is to call one specific function when one specific library is unloaded.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Can't you just run the code in question at the end of you main function?

Answer (score 3):

For Linux systems, the `dlopen()`/`dlclose()` man page explains how to add such a function to your library:

> ## Initialization and finalization functions
>
> Shared  objects  may  export  functions  using  the  `__attribute__((constructor))` and
>   `__attribute__((destructor))` function attributes.  Constructor functions are executed before `dlopen()` returns, and       destructor
>   functions are executed before `dlclose()` returns.  A shared object may
>   export multiple constructors and destructors, and priorities can be
>   associated with each  function  to  determine  the
>          order in which they are executed.  See the gcc info pages (under "Function attributes") for further information.
>
> An  older  method  of  (partially)  achieving the same result is via
>   the use of two special symbols recognized by the linker: `_init` and
>   `_fini`.  If a dynamically loaded shared object exports a routine       named `_init()`, then that code is executed after loading a shared
>   object, before `dlopen()` returns.  If the shared object exports a
>   routine named `_fini()`, then that routine is called  just  before  the 
>   object  is unloaded.  In this case, one must avoid linking against the
>   system startup files, which contain default versions of these files;
>   this can be done by using the gcc(1) `-nostartfiles` command-line
>   option.
>
> Use of `_init` and `_fini` is now deprecated in favor of the
>   aforementioned constructors and destructors, which among other
>   advantages, permit multiple initialization and  finalization 
>   functions  to  be
>          defined.

Answer (score 2):

Solaris and GNU/Linux support the `LD_AUDIT` interface in their dynamic linkers.  You need to load an auditor module which implements the `la_objclose` callback function:

- [Runtime Linker Auditing Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E26507/chapter6-1242.html#indexterm-624)

The implementation can be as simple as this:

```
unsigned int
la_objclose  (uintptr_t *cookie)
{
  printf ("objclose\n");
  return 0;
}
```

In order to determine which object is being closed, you also need to implement `la_objsearch` (and possibly `la_objopen`), to establish a cookie value which somehow refers to the information you need at close time (you could store a pointer to a heap-allocated struct in the cookie, for example).