# Is the unload order of shared libraries well defined at program exit?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have library libfooloader.so which is linked to an application which loads libfoo.so with `dlopen`.

The library reference of libfoo is stored in a RAII wrapped global smart pointer in libfooloader.so.

So when the libfooloader.so is unloaded it should automatically dlclose libfoo too.

However when the program exits, it seems libfoo.so is unloaded first then libfooloader.so which would call the cleanup code of the already unloaded libfoo.so which causes crash. At least it seems to do this.

Since dlopen-ed libraries should be closed by dlclose, failing to do so should cause a leak - at least I thought it will do so. But it seems the dlopened lib is still closed automatically at program exit. Is there a way to control this behavior? If not I will have to eradicate all global state from the lib.

Comment: Why does it matter when all used memory are released by the OS on program exit anyway?

Comment: @MartinWickman Cleanup may do more than just deallocating memory.

Comment: I get that, but each lib's shutdown function should not really depend on other libs for that. Anyway, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551525/hook-function-to-shared-library-unloading) may be helpful regarding shutdown hooks.

Comment: @MartinWickman The actual problem is that there is a third party library that uses its own allocator out of our control. On unload it frees the space of it's allocator making all allocated heap objects dangling. Despite our lib tries to exit cleanly and deallocate everything and calling dlclose finally... The runtime linker kicks the lib away before we had a chance to cleanup properly. I already use __attribute__((destructor)) (more specifically: c++ static objects whose cleanup assigned to the destructor).